# Make similar text bold like Google

Tags: jquery, events, addclass

I have a script which allows to display search results on keyup: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGN8e/3/)

I want to mimic Google by adding a bold effect on the text in results if it matches the value of input. I have a code in which I generate 'tags' like this:

```
var tag = $('#searchbox').val();

if (e.keyCode == 32) {

var div = $('<div class="tags" />');

    div.append(tag);
    $(document.body).append(div);

  }
```

This means if I press the space bar a tag will be generated, which I have given a red color for contrast. Just type something in the searchbox and hit space bar to see the tags. So second Im trying to give a bold font-weight to the matching words in the results, I tried:

```
if($('#searchbox').val() === $('.tags').text()){

 var makeBold = $('.tags').text();

$('#txtresults').addClass(makeBold);
}
```

This doesn't work. I have set these codes in the keyup event way down in the example script.

Comment: I suggest you to clear the tags first and then add the entered tags, because when you enter a tag and press spacebar, then backspace and again spacebar, the tags duplicate.

Comment: @Cobold Should that really matter if I just want to make the matching text bold? I see no problem in duplicated text, as long as the matching text gets bold.

Comment: I just thought it would look pretty messy when someone typed the tags incorrectly then edited them and the incorrect tags would still be there. That's just a suggestion.

Comment: @Cobold Thanks, but the tags will not be visible and I will eventually Clear the HTML('') if value is('')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the code where you display the search results.

You need to search inside the `Description` property for the search terms and wrap them in the element you want..

---

**UPDATE**

You just need to modify the regular expression, used to search, a bit to include multiple terms..

```
var searchRegex = new RegExp(response.SearchResponse.Query.SearchTerms.replace(/\s+/gi,' ').split(' ').join('|'),'gi');
```

**Working example at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGN8e/7/

---

**ORIGINAL CODE**

So change

```
$.each(searchResults, function(i, searchResult) {
    if (searchResult.Description == null) {
        searchResult.Description = '';
    }

    webResultOutput.push('<li>', 
                         '<h3><a href="', searchResult.Url, '">', searchResult.Title, '</a></h3>', 
                         '<p class="desc">',
                         searchResult.Description, 
                         '</p>',
                         '<p class="url">', searchResult.DisplayUrl, '</p>',
                         '</li>');
        });
```

to

```
var searchRegex = new RegExp(response.SearchResponse.Query.SearchTerms,'gi');
$.each(searchResults, function(i, searchResult) {
    if (searchResult.Description == null) {
        searchResult.Description = '';
    }

    webResultOutput.push('<li>', 
                         '<h3><a href="', searchResult.Url, '">', searchResult.Title, '</a></h3>', 
                         '<p class="desc">',
                         searchResult.Description.replace(searchRegex , function(match){ return '<b>'+match+'</b>'}), 
                         '</p>',
                         '<p class="url">', searchResult.DisplayUrl, '</p>',
                         '</li>');
        });
```

**Working example at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGN8e/5/

Comment: Hi, I think this is great and it will definitely help me in one way or the other. But the main reason I created the tags is because of the space bar and multiple words. Your code only heighlights the first query, once you hit space bar nothing is highlighted. Thats why I really would like to use ALL the words in the tags for every query. So 'I like stack' would highlight I - like - stack. I hope you are (still) interested in this challenge..

Comment: @Youss, all the words in the last search query. right ? not previous queries as well.

Comment: The main problem is that if you would type `'I like stack'` it would highlight the exact sentence. But I really would like it to highlight `'Í'` and highlight `'like'` and highlight `'stack'` as Google does. Otherwise a difficult sentence would be highlighted nowhere.

Comment: Thats why I made the tags, becuase it 'splits' the words by space bar.

Comment: @Youss, ok got it.. check updated answer and fiddle.. (*at the top of answer*)

Comment: @Thank you so much:) (Do you think its possible to distinguish by space bar, so that when typing `A` and the space bar it will highlight `A` instead of every A in the results...)

Comment: @Youss, not sure i follow... lets assume that `_` is spacebar pressed. If i search for `a_test` what should it highlight ? and what if i type `a_test_`.

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli If you would type `a_test` it would have to highlight `a` and `test` but not all the `a` in results. So if the results was something like: "Im at stack" It would not highlight the`a` in the word "stack" But if the results was "Im at stack a" it would highlight the 'a' which is on its own, and NOT the `a` which is in "at" and "stack" I hope this makes sence, anyway Im glad you are sticking around:)

Comment: so only highlight full words ? (*in  your first example of **Im at stack** would it not highlight anything ?*)

Comment: If you would press a single A (space) it would hightlight every A in every word, which is wrong. I only want it to highlight A if it is on its own. Because that is what is being typed..

Comment: Just take a look at Google. When you type a single letter, only the matching letter which stands on its own is getting the bold css. But in your code every letter in every word ore sentence is highlighted. I hope Im making sence.

Comment: Ok check out http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGN8e/9/ It matches at word boundaries (*whole words only*). Made some slight changes to only have one running ajax call at a time..

Comment: @Youss btw.. use http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CGN8e/12/ I had an error in the regex.. i should use `\s` for matching whitespace and not `\W` as i did..

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli Thanks for being patient with me, thanks for your effort and time and thanks for solving my problem:)